# Jquery: syntax for inserting a function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to integrate an animation by using the bezier path plug-in and I can't seem to implement it right.

Stripped down, here's what I have:

```
    $('#next2btn').live('click', function(){
       $(this).attr('id','next3btn');
        $('#content2').show(300, function() {
            $('#account').fadeTo(500,1.0)
            var arc_params = {
                center: [278,120],
                radius: 186,
                start: -90,
                end: 90,
                dir: -1
                };
            });
        $("#account").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)},1000);
});
```

So, I'm trying to add this piece of code into what I have:

```
    var arc_params = {
                center: [278,120],
                radius: 186,
                start: -90,
                end: 90,
                dir: -1
              };
        });
$("#account").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)},1000)
```

which works on its own as does the other.

I'm thinking it's something about declaring that variable and where I do that.

I'm essentially chaining a few different animations/actions upon a button click.

Thanks for any insight-
kj

Answer (score 1):

You're right in your assumptions. As you are declaring `arc_params` inside the callback function of `show`, it is only visible inside the function, and not outside of it, it in the following code. Declare it outside the function, so it will be visible to your animate function.

Here's a simple example of how it works, independent of any other code:

```
var a = "outside function";
function someFunction() {
    var b = "inside function";
}

alert(a); //alerts correctly
alert(b); //gives error: 'b is not defined' (as it is not visible from outside the function
```

Comment: Ok, this is making sense. However, I'm thiking in terms of theory now.. using a callback function is the only way I've been able to pause an action. Using delay(xxxx) has never worked but now I think I need to investigate the animation que more and see where/why I started using a callback function to be able to chain stuff. I think it's all the parenthesis and brackets when inserting into an existing function.... actionscript was easier for me for some reason! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That snippet you posted won't work by itself; it's syntactically incorrect (mismatching `)`).

You'll most probably be wanting:

```
$('#next2btn').live('click', function(){
    $(this).attr('id','next3btn');

    $('#content2').show(300, function() {
        $('#account').fadeTo(500,1.0);

        var arc_params = {
                center: [278,120],
                radius: 186,
                start: -90,
                end: 90,
                dir: -1
            };

        $("#account").animate({
            path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

(which of course, is equivilent to:)

```
$('#next2btn').live('click', function(){
    $(this).attr('id','next3btn');

    $('#content2').show(300, function() {
        $('#account').fadeTo(500,1.0);

        $("#account").animate({
            path : new $.path.arc({
                center: [278,120],
                radius: 186,
                start: -90,
                end: 90,
                dir: -1
            })
        }, 1000);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: They're equivalent with regards to `arc_params` being sent inline in the second example, but `$('#account').animate()` will fire on different times in the two examples. Guess it's just a typo :)

Comment: @Simen: Whoops... indeed. Thanks.